# Using self in modules

Tags: ruby

Is there a difference between the following two examples? Is it possible to get method conflicts in the second example because of method names? Aren't methods within a module automatically "encapsulated" within this module?

Example 1

```
module ImageUtils
  def self.preview(image)
    #do something
  end
end
```

Example 2

```
module ImageUtils
  def preview(image)
    #do something
  end
end
```

If I would put everything into a class `Foo` within the module `ImageUtils`, how would this differ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that first example defines ***module method*** called `preview`, and second example defines ***mixin method*** `preview`.

So that if you include first module into a class, you'll be able to call this method on the class (whereas calling the method on the class instance would cause the error), while including the second module into the class will allow you to call the method on class' instances, but calling the method on the class itself will cause

```
NoMethodError: undefined method preview for Foo:Class
```

Regarding conflicts basing on the same method name in class and module included to it. Answer to this question lays in Ruby method lookup, which is following:

1. Methods from the object's singleton/meta/eigen class
2. Methods from prepended modules (Ruby 2.0+ feature)
3. Methods from the object's class
4. Methods from included modules
5. Methods from the class hierarchy (superclass and its ancestors)

Method lookup stops, when the method is found.

With `prepend` the mixin method will have precedence in method lookup;

With `include` method defined in class has the precedence in method lookup.

**So no conflicts are possible.**

Comment: I'm aware of class and instance method, just wanted to be sure that it doesn't really change anything in how namespacing works.

Comment: it is only a matter on your intention regarding method usage - will it be used on class or on it's instances

Comment: technically it's not a class method but an instance method of singleton class.

Comment: Class methods belong to classes. This is a module method that's directly accessible. I tend to differentiate between the two types here by calling the first example a "module method" and the second a "mixin method" since it must be imported with `include` before it can be used.